# Send a 2d PROGMEM array over SoftwareSerial

Tags: serial, softwareserial, array, progmem

I have a 2d array:

```
const byte messages_for_measurement[2][8] PROGMEM = 
{
  { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08 },
  { 0x09, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E, 0x0F, 0x10 },
};
```

I want to send one of these sub-array over software serial.

Initially, this produced junk data:

```
swSerial.write( messages_for_measurement[0], sizeof(messages_for_energy_meter[0]) );
```

Then I learned about `pgm_read_byte_near()` and `pgm_read_word()`. I tried every combination but I did not get this to work:

```
swSerial.write(pgm_read_byte_near(pgm_read_word(messages_for_measurement[0]))), sizeof(pgm_read_byte_near(pgm_read_word(messages_for_measurement[0])));
```

and

```
swSerial.write(pgm_read_byte_near(&pgm_read_word(messages_for_measurement[0]))), sizeof(pgm_read_byte_near(pgm_read_word(&messages_for_measurement[0])));
```

and

```
swSerial.write(char(pgm_read_byte_near(pgm_read_word(messages_for_measurement[0])))), sizeof(char(pgm_read_byte_near(pgm_read_word(messages_for_measurement[0]))));
```

and

```
swSerial.write(char(pgm_read_byte_near(pgm_read_word(&messages_for_measurement[0])))), sizeof(char(pgm_read_byte_near(pgm_read_word(&messages_for_measurement[0]))));
```

How can I send the sub-array over serial, when the 2d array is in PROGMEM?

Answer (score 1):

The `write()` method from `SoftwareSerial` (which is inherited from the
abstract `Print` class) does not support printing PROGMEM-based binary
buffers. The `print()` method does have some PROGMEM support, but it is
limited to printing NUL-terminated character strings, and is meant to be
used with the `F()` macro. You could coerce this method into printing
your data, but this would require you to add a null byte at the end of
each inner array, and the trick would break if you ever have to send a
null byte.

Also, the `pgm_read_stuff()` macros cannot read an array at a time. You
could do achieve this with `memcpy_P()`, but that would require
allocating an array in RAM. I think the simplest solution here is to get
the bytes from the flash one by one with `pgm_read_byte()`:

```cpp
const byte *message = messages_for_measurement[0];
size_t size = sizeof messages_for_measurement[0];
for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    swSerial.write(pgm_read_byte(&message[i]));
}
```

Note that the first line does not attempt to access the array data: it
only copies into `message` the address of the first byte: this is the
decay-to-pointer semantics.